# Open cursors in Oracle while updating a column with null value

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, spring-data

I am facing a strange issue with Oracle. In my update query if I update a column with **null** then it leaves open cursor. If I replace same query with update value from **null** to "" then the cursor closes.

Very strange!!

Not sure whether it is configuration issue.

Environment Details:

```
Jdk 1.8
Oracle 12c
Spring 3.1 Jdbctemplate and preparedstatement
Ojdbc7 driver
DBCP connection pooling
```

Please help me understand the issue and possible way to fix it, if any.

Updates:
On debugging the code, while setting null, looks like OracleParameterMetaDataParser.getParameterMetaDataSql() is throwing exception  ORA-00904: "F": invalid identifier and the cursors are not closed. So for each null column one cursor gets open and never closed.

Is it a driver issue? Any idea.

Comment: Do you have any constraints on that column like NOT NULL? You can see that using desc table_name;

Comment: Thanks JavaHopper. I checked the table those columns allow null.

Comment: so, were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: No....the column allows null, so the update with null works but leaves open cursors.

Comment: pl/sql code, can you please put it here, if that is not too long?

Comment: I am using prepared statement, so the query is like 'update test set test1=?, test2=?, test3=?, test4=? where test5=?' where test1 have a value 0.
test2, test3, test4 are blank
and test5 have a valid value

Comment: Show us your stored procedure (the PL/SQL code)